# UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath is called but data source is empty

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a custom tab on top of view which a user can switch two view back and forth. Both view contains UICollectionView dynamically filled with data from a server. In my understanding, if `numberOfItemInSection` return 0 when `[collectionView reloadData]` is called, `cellForItemAtIndexPath` won't be called. In other word, if `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is being called, it means there is some data in source. Below is some code I used when switch to one view to other view.

```
- (void)refresh
{
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
    [self.data removeAllObjects];
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    if (self.collectionView.contentOffset.y == 0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^(void){
            self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -MPViewHeight(self.refreshControl));
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        }];
    }
    [self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
    [self requestToServerAtIndex:0];
}


- (void) requestToServerAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    @weakify(self)
    [[self.serverHelper getData:index requestCount:20] subscribeNext:^(id JSON) {
        @strongify(self)
        NSArray *data = [ParserForJSON parse:JSON];

        if(data.count != 20) {
            self.moreData = NO;
        }

        [self.data addObjectsFromArray:data];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    } error:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.data.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomData *data = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ///.... some cell configuration

    return cell;
}
```

However, I got random crash on `cellForItemAtIndexPath` when it tried to access data source which was happened to be empty. Surprisingly, the data source was not empty when I checked on console at that point. So my wild guess is there was some timing issue. I would like to get some in depth explanation on this ambiguous behavior.

Comment: Can you show your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and your `numberOfItemsInSection`?  Does `subscribeNext` make sure to dispatch the completion block on the main queue?

Comment: RACSignal that delivers data was on `[RACScheduler scheduler]`. should I deliver it on mainThread when I call subscribeNext?

Comment: Iet's say subscribeNext wasn't dispatched to main queue. But if `cellForItemAtIndexPath` was called which means  `numberOfItemsInSection` was called successfully, then shouldn't data source be ready to use?

Comment: I would try wrapping your `reloadData` and `endRefreshing` in a dispatch main - updating UI elements from a background thread can result in strange behaviour.  Also be wary of updating an NSMutableArray from multiple threads as it isn't thread safe

Comment: I see, you got some points. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `refresh` method, you remove all `data` objects, so when your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` was called, there's no data in `data` source. That's why when call `id object = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` return `nil`. So make sure  after `requestToServerAtIndex` make the new datas realy then remove the old objects and update the UI.

EDIT:
Try to remove  `[self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];` to test, this method should call `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: I doubt your argument is correct. Because self.data is empty, which means cellForItemAtIndexPath won't be called.

Comment: Actually, you could have a race condition because you empty the array before you start loading and you don't reload the view at that point, so the view still thinks it has a non-zero number of cells.  It is safer to load into another array and swap those values into `self.data` just before you call reload on the view

Comment: Don't forget you called: [self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];